# Flutter FirebaseFirestore where condition returning related and unrelated values

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am querying a firestore collection in Flutter using where and arrayContains, for some reason it is not working as expected for me.

```
      StreamBuilder(
          stream: (_searchTerm.length >= 3)
              ? FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").snapshots()
              : FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('users')
                  .where('email', arrayContains: _searchTerm)
                  .snapshots(),
          builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
            final results = snapshot.data.docs;
            print(results.length);
            return ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: results.length,
              itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => Text(
                results[index].data()['display-name'],
              ),
            );
          })
```

The _searchTerm variable is populated as I type in some values into the textfield and when it hits a length of three characters that's when the above query fires.
For example when I type in **test** the query should only return the values that contain **test** in it, but I am getting the whole collection with and without the value test.
Please advice!

EDIT - Posting a screenshot of my firestore data structure
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do the following:

```dart
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('users')
  .where('email', arrayContains: _searchTerm)
  .snapshots(),
```

You are looking for documents inside the `users` collection that have `_searchTerm` as an item of the `email` array, property of a `user` document.

There are two problems:

1. I don't think the `email` property of your `users` is an array.
2. Firebase does  not perform substring searches

I think you will need to use a third-party application for searches on Firestore. A popular one is [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/) that comes with a quite powerful FREE plan.

Comment: I have added the data structure to the original post. Is the search not possible with that data structure? could you please check. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you see, the `email` is a `String`, not an `array`. When you perform `.where(property, arrayContains: value)` on a query, it will try to find all the documents with an array named `property` that contains `value` as an item of the array. It will not work on `email` because its a String and not an array. It will also not work on `searchTerm` because it will be a partial value.

Comment: Oh is it, is there no other way I could make this work other than using a 3rd party application?

Comment: I'm afraid not. And, by the way, Algolia is the solution recommended by Google: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/solutions/search